# Remotely connect to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, remote-access

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop a Windows form that binds data from a SQL Server database. I want this form to connect to a SQL Server database that is on my server. To try to connect to the server, I do the following:

```
SQL Server Object Explorer -> Add Server -> Browse for more -> Network Servers
```

It does not appear in it. Even if I just type the name of the server on the server name I get error 87.

My local machine is using Windows 8, and my server is Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2014 Express Edition with Advance Services.

Please, help me with the connection.

Edit:

On the server end I did the following

```
SQL Server Configuration Manager
 -> SQL Server Network Configuration
   -> tcp/ip-> enable -> IPALL -> TCP PORT -> 1433

windows firewall advanced settings
   -> inbound -> add new rule -> port -> 1433 
      -> allow connections
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect using the server ip address instead of the server name?

Comment: @JeffBeese yes. Server Name: "ServerIPAddress":1433. I get the same error 87 ("server not found or inaccesible")

Comment: Express often exposes as Servername:Express.  What is the name of the Service?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the server using Management Studio? If not, check in the SQL Server Configuration Manager you have enabled TCP connection for express edition of SQL server and you have enabled remote connection (TCP port 1433) in windows firewall.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

enable the IP that you want to connect 
for example i'm using local host 
you can use your PC IP :192.168.1.2
or you can use public IP if you have public IP